# PHP: Unknown MySQL server host with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'dbname';
$dbh = new mysqli('p:'.$host, $username, $password, $db) 
    or die('no connection to server');
```

But I get the following error

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli() [<a href='function.mysqli-mysqli'>function.mysqli-mysqli</a>]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'p:localhost' (1) in /var/www/vhosts/politiker.lu/httpdocs/includes/sql.php on line 8
```

This intrigues me because the very same code worked on my development environment. Now that I want to set it up on my production server, it does not work. Any ideas?

Note: I am not very good with servers, so excuse me if the error should be something trivial.

#### EDIT 1

Here are the versions:
Development PHP (5.3.3-1ubuntu9.1) + MySQL(5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1)
Production PHP (5.2.4-2ubuntu5.12) + MySQL(5.0.51a)

Comment: Maybe your versions of PHP and/or mysqli are different in the two environments?  Maybe the version on the production server doesn't support persistent connections?

Comment: What if you just remove the p: part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

take out the `p:` like this:

```
$dbh = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db) 
    or die('no connection to server');
```

Comment: `p:` is supposed to indicate persistent connections.

Comment: I did try and remove the persistent connection. However, I get the following error "There is no 'root'@'localhost' registered. This is even more weird, since I never asked for the root user.

Comment: So then it connected to mysql, thats progress! =]

Comment: Are you trying to call a stored procedure ?

Comment: Or create a stored procedure ?   it could be a definer problem

Comment: @superfro: Yes. I am trying something new with this one though. My setup allows the user only to execute the stored procedures. A second username, which guests cannot access, is used to do the more serious SQL work.

Comment: Please check the procedure if you have a definer set, if you do it tries to execute as that user unless you change the sql_security to invoker, which is a plausable cause for that error.  But taking out p: did let you connect to mysql now correct?

Comment: @superfro: You were right about this one. I have different admin names for dev and production systems. Why the hell Plesk would use that username I don't know... Well, it seems to work now without persistent connections.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding this since I didn't think it was clear, but the problem is definitely your production version of PHP. Persistent connections for the mysqli extensions weren't added until 5.3 since they caused headaches before.

Some hosts might have different versions of PHP installed... I realized today that I can make HostGator use PHP 5.3! I just had to add to my .htaccess file:

```
Action application/x-hg-php53 /cgi-sys/php53
AddType application/x-hg-php53 .php
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you missed the mysqli package in this server. Try :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqli
```

if apt-get says it is already installed try to do a ping to localhost, if don't resolve edit /etc/hosts and check the line where localhost points to 127.0.0.1
should be there, if not, your server its horribly configured!

do a

```
ifconfig
```

and check if you get some output like this...

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

Comment: Tried that. It says that "the following packages replace it: php5-mysql". That package, I already have installed.

Comment: also try 127.0.0.1 instead localhost... you get the same error?

Comment: I get the same error. It does seem to only affect the persistent connection, because as soon as I remove the 'p:', it does work as intended.

Comment: so , i recommend dont use persistent connections, i benchmarked two years ago, no benefit performance remarkable using p connects.

Comment: i ve found this article: it seems persistent connections in mysqli are disabled. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/12/are-php-persistent-connections-evil/

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the actual location of the MySQL server. For development, it is `localhost` (most likely), just how you have it configured. But for production servers, it is going to be something else. I doubt it should be `localhost`.

Comment: "Unknown MySQL server host" - What else would you guess it could be?

Comment: I own a virtual server. I actually have Mysql Workbench up and running (Query Browser and Admin Interface) up and running with TCP/IP via ssh, which in turn connects to 'localhost'.

Comment: @SimpleCoder I am trying to learn though. I usually leave that stuff to people who know how to work with this, but in this case, I required something that I could control myself.

Comment: @Mike; Wow, I am so sorry. For a second there I thought you and the OP were two different people. I hope I didn't offend you.

Comment: Do you use MySQL Workbench to connect to your development server, or your production server?

Comment: @SimpleCoder: I have both running. All on default ports, nothing fancy.